# Product of a subgroup with index 2 with another is the whole group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H,K\le G$ be two subgroups of $G$ with $K\not\le H$ and $[G:H]=2$. Then, is $HK=G$?

I think yes, but am stammering in the proof. The index of $2$ suggests normality and hence, that maybe $HK$ is a subgroup. But, how could we show that $|HK|=|G|$? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Hint: Use Lagrange

Comment: @MichaelBurr by lagrange,we get $|H|=\frac{|G|}{2}$. What next?

Comment: @MichaelBurr any hints?

Comment: $HK$ is larger than $H$, what is a divisor of $|G|$ larger than $|H|$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr thanks. But, is the proof valid for infinite groups?

Comment: No, the proof in the given answer applies for infinite groups.

Comment: You could still finish the proof using this method.
$HK$ is a subgroup of of $G$ containing $H$.
Since $H$ is normal in $G$ and $G/H$ has order $2$, the Correspondence Theorem tells you that $HK=H$ or $HK=G$.
The hypothesis rules out the first case.

Comment: This approach is more flexible, for example it would still work if you were told that $H$ was normal of prime index in $G$.

Comment: @verret thanks for the great discussion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $K \nsubseteq H$, there is $a \in K \setminus H$, and $aH \ne H$, so $HK \supseteq H \cup aH = G$.

Comment: Typo$ { } { } $